# How do I push my Bitbucket repo to my DigitalOcean server?

Tags: django, git, nginx, version-control, digital-ocean

I've created a DigitalOcean server (droplet) for my Django site, running Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx & Gunicorn.

I've got my Django project in a Bitbucket repo - how do I push this to my DigitalOcean server? I've tried to search and there are many different/confusing answers and they all seem more complicated that it should be. Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need more than just `ssh do-server 'cd /path/to/repo && git pull'`?

Answer (score 0):

1. mkdir path/to/project
2. cd path/to/project
3. git init
4. git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/bucket/remository.git